# Creating a column that counts the distance between like numbers in another column

Tags: r, excel

Okay, I know that title is probably confusing.  Sorry about that.  I have a dataframe with lottery jackpots by draw and run since 2008.  I would like to create a new column that counts the number of draws since the jp value for that draw had a similar value (either exactly the same, or, even better, within 10%).

So, I have

```
run draw   jp
74      1     15
74      2     20
74      3     25
75      1     15
75      2     20
76      1     15
76      2     20
76      3     26
```

and want to know that when run 76, draw 3 hit 26, it had been 5 draws since a similar jp.  For every observation all the way down.

So, the data would end up looking like:

```
run draw   jp    draws sincelikejp
74      1     15    na
74      2     20    na
74      3     25    na
75      1     15    3
75      2     20    3
76      1     15    2
76      2     20    2
76      3     26    5
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I do not understand what the result would look like, can you give an example?

Comment: @MarkHeckmann, I edited the original question to show output.

The actual dataset is around 1000 observations, so I'm trying to figure out a way to automate it.

Answer (score 2):

```
DF <- read.table(text="run draw   jp
74      1     15
74      2     20
74      3     25
75      1     15
75      2     20
76      1     15
76      2     20
76      3     26", header=TRUE)

tmp <- outer(DF$jp, DF$jp, function(a, b) abs(b-a)/b)
tmp[lower.tri(tmp)] <- NA
DF$since <- apply(tmp, 2, function(x) {
                    res <- diff(tail(which(x < 0.1), 2))
                    if (length(res) == 0) return(NA) else return(res)
                    })
#   run draw jp since
# 1  74    1 15    NA
# 2  74    2 20    NA
# 3  74    3 25    NA
# 4  75    1 15     3
# 5  75    2 20     3
# 6  76    1 15     2
# 7  76    2 20     2
# 8  76    3 26     5
```